# How do I Set Specific Characters as Different Colors in Multidimensional Arrays

Tags: c++, arrays

So in my programming class we are supposed to make a multi-dimensional array that sets all values to 0 in 1 function and then randomizes it so some of the zeros are replaced by an "X" in another function, which is shown below. I would like to know how to have these random values be a different color.

```
    void specialInit(char grid[ROW][COLUMN])
    {
       for(int j = 0; j < ROW; j++)
       {
           for(int i = 0; i < COLUMN; i++)
           { 
               int dig = ((rand() + time(0)) % 9)+1;
               if (dig < 3)
               {
                   grid[j][i] = 'X', SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), FOREGROUND_GREEN | BACKGROUND_BLUE);
               }
           }
       }
   }
```

Comment: What's the comma for as in `X`, `SetConsoleTextAttribute`?

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion is to use a matrix of `struct` rather than characters:

```
struct Char_Property
{
  char  c;
  unsigned int color;
};
//...
Char_Property grid[ROW][COLUMN];
```

Another method is to have a parallel matrix with the colors:

```
unsigned int grid_color[ROW][COLUMN];
```

Before you output the `grid` character, set the attribute property, retrieved from the either the struct or `grid_color`, then output the `grid` character.

A third alternative is to apply the color attributes as your print:

```
for (unsigned int r = 0; r < ROW; ++r)
{
  for (unsigned int c = 0; c < COLUMN; c++)
  {
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(/*...*/);
    cout << grid[r][c];
  }
  cout << "\n";
}
```